# Error loading CSV column in datetime format into BigQuery DATETIME column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV file from Google Storage into a BigQuery table using `LOAD DATA INTO`. This file contains matching schema with the table. As a matter of fact the schema from the source table is identical to the one being uploaded to and the CSV file itself was exported to CSV using `EXPORT DATA`.

When loading BigQuery raises the following error:

```
Invalid value: Invalid schema update. Field dt_created has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP
```

Both columns in the BQ tables are in format `DATETIME` and the CSV file is in the expected ISO8601 format.

| dt_created |
| --- |
| 2021-09-22 11:47:09 |
| 2021-09-22 11:47:22 |

I have recreated the procedure on a sample table and suffer the same results. I have tried casting to `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` before exporting using `EXPORT DATA` to no effect.

The BigQuery documentation on loading CSV data (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv) states that

> Datetime. Columns with DATETIME types must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.SSSSSS]

which is correct in my case, however -- and similarly -- for `TIMESTAMP`

> Timestamp. BigQuery accepts various timestamp formats. The timestamp must include a date portion and a time portion.
>
> The date portion can be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD.
>
> The timestamp portion must be formatted as HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]] (seconds and fractions of seconds are optional).

Is there any way or option to make BigQuery infer this column as `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on second glance of the docs, make sure to define column names and data types, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA INTO `project.dataset.table`(dt_datetime DATETIME)
FROM FILES (format = "CSV", skip_leading_rows=1, uris=[...])
```